# WordPress do_action and add_action; running arguments in add_action call

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently writing a plugin for WordPress, and I'm stumped with the `add_action` and `do_action` functions. I think I may be trying to use them in the wrong context, and if that's the case - could someone point me in the right direction?

I've come from hating WordPress to loving it, I never thought I'd write a wordpress plugin but now I am getting the hang of things, it's not all that different from normal PHP Development.

Anyway, if I was to have the following code in a plugin:

```
class aCoolPlugin {

    function __construct() {
        add_action('clear_auth_cookie', array( $this, 'aCoolFunction' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    function aCoolFunction( $arg1, $arg2 ) {
        // Do something with the arguments
    }

}
```

How would I actually run the `aCoolFunction` function? Now, I have tried the following:

`do_action( 'init', "arg1 value", "arg2 value" );`

However, before even trying to run that code I realised:

1. It makes no sense, since it will essentially be running the `init` action far too early, and;
2. It just doesn't work anyway!

So, from that I learnt:

1. I use `add_action` to hook into already existing functions for WP
2. `do_action` is reserved for new hooks really, can't really think of a useful situation where a hook should be called earlier, and then again later?

So, my question now is: How the heck can I pass my variables into the `add_action` code? The [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) doesn't say anything regarding arguments, **so what are my options?** *or, is my logic and understanding flawed?*

**And what is the overall goal?** The goal is to have a function with set arguments run every time a specific hook is called, and for the original hook to not be called any earlier/later than it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add action does not accept any new variables nor will it return any variables to the function that runs it. But you can access variables that are passed to the function.

```
function custom_function($arga){
       echo $arga;
}

add_action ('callname', 'custom_function', 10, 1);// 1= number of arguments accepted, use 2 for 2 etc...must add variables to do action call


//sometime later in the code
do_action('callname', $arga);
```

If you want to inject variables in you have to think a little bit back to basics. If you want to access variables within functions that are not passed you have 2 options:

1. Retrieve them from DB or server storage or similar
2. Use the Global declaration. You can accesss all variables that are set at the time the do_action is run.

You would rarely call do_action for wordpress hooks (see note below), but you may end up in a situation where you are coding a template FILE (which runs after plugins and then after themes) and you want to keep your logic in the plugin  you could add `do_action()` into the template file and the actions set in the plugin will run at that point. Or similarly if you design a plugin that you want to be able to modify in the theme you could add an action to a late wp hook, within the called function, you could call do_action for your custom hook and hook functions to it in your theme. Loads of possibilities.

**Whatever your logic for calling a WP hook early is, *don't* if you are within the WP load pattern**